# Database design including people and organisation

Tags: database-design, relational-database, subtyping

I recently discovered the subtype/supertype method in relational database design and therefore this question: is this a correct design mixed with subtype/supertype design method?

Before I have addressed `persons` and `organisations` as two distinct types. I understand that it's a better method to have `party` a supertype of `people` and `organisation`. Now, having that settled, adding `adresses` and `additional_addresses` both apply for `organisations` as well as for `persons`, thus connecting them to the supertype `parties`.

Furthermore, different groups of people I need to keep records of, like `employees`, `projectcontacts` and `suppliercontacts`. These are all distinct types of `persons`, within a `party`. Is this a correct way of joining the table with `persons` to accomplish this goal? Same goes for `suppliers` and `debtors`, linked to the `organisation` table, since `supplier` and `debtors` are always `organisations`.

I believe this is a good way of design but I might miss out something with the primary and foreign keys, especially when looking at `SupplierContacts`. There is a foreign key of `partyid` which should refer to a `person`, and also a foreign key of `supplierid`, but this `supplierid` also refers to a certain `partyid` in its own table. Won't this be a ridiculously hard work to be able to query information out of this table and is this design even a proper one?

My main concern is the fact that many tables need to refer to a person **ÓR** an organisation, and instead of having two foreign keys everywhere, leaving one NULL at all times since I store a record of either a `person` **OR** an `organisation`, now I only have one foreign key: `partyid`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer relies on the [art of designing primary keys](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html).
You have used [surrogate identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) as the primary key for `parties` table (one of the common pitfalls of developers), in the mean time this is not possible to detect a row in `parties` table is actually a person or organization with out joining to persons or organization tables. 
So when ever you use the PK of `parties` as a FK in other table, that wouldn't be detectable if the party is the desired one, you are loosing business logic, its the side effect of using surrogate key.
**Solution:** Choose a natural key for parties table.
It would be recommended to have a discriminator column in parties table called `party_type` (an enumeration, values would be person=1 and organization=2). 
The primary key of the parties table could be `{party_name + party_type}`.
In the aggregation tables like `SupplierContacts` having a check constraint on `{party_type = 1`} will solve the problem.
Note that the solution is aimed to solved the problem in database-design level, as an alternative you can extra work in your application level to archive data integrity (less advised yet mostly used by developers !)

Comment: What do you mean by ´that wouldn't be detectable if the party is the desired one´? I normally don't want to refer to party table on it's own, if that is what you mean (I see now that partyname is an irrelevant attribute), always in combination of `persons` or `organisations` because that will ultimately design the form fields in the GUI of the application - form for info of people or form for info of companies/organisations. Though I do need the information of the addresses and addinfo in the party table

Reading further on the surrogate identifier, the plan was to determine the ID's as GUIDs

Comment: In my opinion to overcome the problem 'instead of having two foreign keys everywhere, leaving one NULL ' you need to refer to parties table. To maintain the data integrity you need to keep person-type part of the PK of parties. may GUID+person-type can be the key.

Comment: It is possible to check if records out of people or records out of organisations are filled in when querying, which in my opinion also maintain integrity, but having an extra type check might be better for certain CRUD operations, especially when using multiple records, and possibly also easier to query. Thank you, I will go for the types, either in an attribute, mixed with the PK or both. I will dig a little deeper in that one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on the question you're asking here.

I'm not aware of any database engines that support subtyping natively - they are used for conceptual modeling, and in the physical design they are implemented with whatever the database engine will support.

It may be much more useful to model this as a physical data model - because your decision about primary and foreign keys will almost certainly have to change depending on the way in which you physically represent the sub types.

There are several ways of converting the logical concept of "sub type" to a physical data model - the 3 most common are:

- table per subtype. This means your foreign keys may need to link to multiple tables (e.g. "person" or "organisation"), but your queries/joins are straightforward.
- supertype table with common attributes, separate tables for subtype data (e.g. "party", "person" and "organisation") - in this case your foreign key goes to "party", but to get the subtype data, you have to include the join to the subtype table. This complicates your SQL.
- common table with lots of nullable columns (e.g. "party" with all columns for person and organisation). This makes the foreign key simple - but again, your data access logic gets messy.

To help you evaluate the design, it's worth working through obvious questions like "what's the phone number of supplier x's main contact?", "how many people work on project y?" as SQL queries and see how your schema supports this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.This model might a little be unclear and fast designed, that's why some tables differ from the plural form I intended to write for table names. This is a small piece of the real structure, where i.e. Employees have more information stored, like initials and functions. Suppliers also have information stored about if they are suppliers for servicing and maintenance or for placed orders. My questing mainly concerns the logical design, since I never used super/subtypes before, I wondered if this is a correct way to represent the information I want to store seperately

Comment: Table per subtype is what I tried to avoid so choose for the supertype table with common attributes. Complicated queries are indeed the conns as I was afraid of, but this seems a more logical design. Thanks for reply, I will close the question now.